# app cannot find directory of images inside SD Card

Tags: java, android

Hello guys i am creating an app that will display images in gridview but the problem is the app cannot find the directory of the images inside the SDcard.

here's the code for that.

```
public class Utils {

private Context _context;

public Utils(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}

public ArrayList<String> getFilePaths() {
    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<String>();

    File directory = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
                                + AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM);

    if(directory.isDirectory()) {
        File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();

    if(listFiles.length > 0) {

        for(int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++) {

            String filePath = listFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();

            if(IsSupportedFile(filePath)) {
                filePaths.add(filePath);
            }

            }

        }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(_context, AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM + "is empty. Please load some images", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(_context);
        alert.setTitle("Error!");
        alert.setMessage(AppConstant.PHOTO_ALBUM + " directory path is not valid!");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        alert.show();
    }
    return filePaths;
}

private boolean IsSupportedFile(String filePath) {
    String ext = filePath.substring((filePath.lastIndexOf(".") + 1), filePath.length());

    if(AppConstant.FILE_EXTENSION.contains(ext.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()))) 
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public int getScreenWidth() {
    int columnWidth;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    final Point point = new Point();
    try {
        display.getSize(point);
    } catch(java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) {
        point.x = display.getWidth();
        point.y = display.getHeight();
    }

    columnWidth = point.x;
    return columnWidth;
}
```

hopefully you can help me with this guys.. i dont know how will i access the SDcard through the use of that function

Comment: Have you added permission in manifest file to access SD card??

Comment: have you tried debugging this code?

Comment: @Anil nope i have not declared anything in the manifest sir..

Comment: @ScaryWombat i tried debugging it sir.

Comment: @user3818824...check the answer below added by me to add permission in manifest file.

Comment: @Anil Can i ask something? can i edit the File directory? and make it as something like this? /storage/SdCard/directory name?

Comment: @check answer for your question in the below answer comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no issues that I can see with your code. Just make sure that the user has given the app permission on the manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 0):

To write to external storage, you must have to declare this in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: okay i will also try it if it got errors again.. thanks for helping me. i'll inform you if i get it.

Comment: Colud you debug your code to where the exact error is or show the logcat